# How to remove the class again with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I am creating a memory game and when I click a card of the game I add a `class` to it. I want it the remove the class when 2 cards are flipped. The problem is that I cannot remove/replace the `class` I dynamically created. Tried classList.remove() / classList.add() ...

```
const titleId = document.querySelector(".page-header");
const cardId = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
var cardCounter = 0;

// give the clicked card a class of .card-flipped
// when 2 cards are flipped, activate the function flipCardBack
for (let i = 0; i < cardId.length; i++) {
cardId[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    cardId[i].classList.add("card-fliped");
    cardCounter ++;

    if (cardCounter === 2){
        cardCounter = 0;
        setTimeout(flipCardBack, 2500);
        }

    });
}

// trying to remove the added class .card-flipped (currently not working)

function flipCardBack() {
let dynamicClassSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".card-fliped");
dynamicClassSelector.classList.remove("card-flipped");
}
```

the error message I get is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
>       at flipCardBack.

Comment: `flipped` or `fliped`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements, if you want to remove the class, you'll have to loop through this list and remove the class from each element, here is an example:

```
function flipCardBack() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".card-fliped").forEach(element => {
    element.classList.remove("card-fliped");
  })
}
```

As @Andreas has mentioned, you also have a typo, you've used both `card-fliped` and `card-flipped` (with one and two `p`s).

Comment: `"card-fliped" !== "card-flipped"`

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `flipped` when you add the class :)

Should be

```
cardId[i].classList.add("card-flipped");
```

not

```
cardId[i].classList.add("card-fliped");
```

Oh and also when you query the document - you need to use the same spelling - perhaps even extract that string to a constant so you make sure to use the same string ;)

Also the `querySelectorAll` will return an list of elements matching, so you'll want to do it on each/first whatever on that collection.

Comment: If you change this typo you will also have to change the typo in `flipCardBack()`.

Comment: Yeah - it needs to be consistent - so either change flipped to fliped once or fliped to flipped twice :P